# What is the perfect toolbox for PL/SQL development?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I work on two projects with a lot of PL/SQL code since few months.

However, I didn't find any really interesting tools to develop on this langage.

For the moment, my configuration includes the following tools:

- [Eclipse](http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-2.1.0.62.61-no-jre.zip) (the rest of the application is developed in Java), with [PL/SQL Editor plugin](http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper-2.1.0.62.61-no-jre.zip)
- As I really don't like and trust the PL/SQL Editor plugin for Eclipse, I use mainly [PsPad](http://www.pspad.com) for editing my PL/SQL files.
- [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) (I have also TOAD, but I don't really know/like this tool).

So what is your "perfect" toolbox for developing PL/SQL applications?

I've also read that SQL Developer 2.1 introduces a PL/SQL unit testing feature. Does anybody has a feedback about this feature and this version of SQL Developer (I still use 1.5) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being an old-fashioned sort of chap I still mainly get along with SQL*Plus and [the TextPad IDE](http://www.textpad.com/).  TextPad is nagware, but the licence is cheap and the tool has some fantastic features.  Also people have written PLSQL syntax libraries for it, which give you keyword highlighting.   It is also possible to hook TextPad into other desktop tools such as [Subversion](http://johnbokma.com/textpad/textpad-subversion.html).

SQL^Developer is written in java, which means it is a voracious consumer of memory.  Still there is undoubted merit in having a data browser.  Also the upcoming version 2.1 features [built-in unit test](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/11gr2_db_prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_unit_test/sqldev_unit_test_otn.htm), which could be very tasty.

**Useful utilities:**

- [pldoc](http://pldoc.sourceforge.net/) :: generate Javadoc-style
  documentation from the comments in
  your package spec
- [utplplsql](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/) :: unit test harness;
  old but it still works
- [QUTO](http://unittest.inside.quest.com/index.jspa) :: another, more
  sophisticated unit test harness
  (which I don't use for the same
  reason I'm still hacking with
  SQL*Plus and TextPad)
- [QGCU](http://qcgu.net/) :: PL/SQL code generator
  (previously QNXO)

**In defence of Luddism**

The danger with tools like TOAD and SQL*Developer is that they allow us to execute DML and DDL directly against the database, including editing PL/SQL source.  This is fine and dandy and awfully in the spirit of Getting Things Done.  Until we need to revert our changes.  Or the production DBA demands a script....

Of course it is possible to use TOAD or SQL Developer in a safe fashion - I know SQL Developer can hook into source control as well - if just requires more self-discipline.

Comment: +1 for SQL Plus and TextPad, with just a smattering of SQL Developer for data browsing.  Exactly what I do!

Comment: TOAD also hooks into version control.  Developer workflow is more about discipline than anything.  You can edit files in the file system, check them in with a 3rd party tool and then run a build script to have them propogate.

Comment: You have to bug the SQL Developer folks that they should provide DDL "source code" for every action you do in the GUI, so you can easier create a script. I created a request "Show DDL commands issued after editing table in GUI" in their feature tracker, you are welcome to vote for it.

Answer (score 7):

I always liked the [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) by Allround Automations - an excellent, quick and easy to use, and totally affordable tool!

For an interactive query shell - much better than SQL*Plus - I used to use "[Golden](http://www.benthicsoftware.com/index.htm)" - a nice and powerful shareware tool, highly recommended.

Much better than anything else I ever tried with Oracle.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Might be a slightly different answer than you were expecting but I feel the Oracle [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage) and in particular [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/toc.htm)  book should be essential for any PL/SQL toolbox.

Comment: For me, those are resources, not tools!

Comment: @Romaintaz we'll have to agree to disagree!

Answer (score 1):

My primary editor for PL/SQL packages is SlickEdit.
SlickEdit offers good support for PL/SQL development, though you might miss the direct connection to the database that tools like TOAD or SQLDeveloper offer.
On the other hand, working on PL/SQL files (instead of directly working on database objects, like many TOAD users do) is IMO a good practice for any non-trivial project.
In addition to SlickEdit, I use a few self-made helper programs, e.g. one that loads source code from the database and creates a source file, and another one that compiles the source and calculates the correct line numbers for errors in a file that contains multible objects, e.g. both package specification and body.

For direct database access, I prefer SQLDeveloper, mostly because it's free and works well on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

- Eclipse as the IDE
- [Toby's PLSQL Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plsqleditor/) as the PLSQL Eclipse plugin
- TOAD as the database tool
- utplsql and OUnit as the unit test framework
- Ant as the build tool
- CVS as the source control tool
- pldoc as the documentation tool
- CruiseControl as the continuous integration tool

[Toby's PLSQL Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plsqleditor/) can do:

- Syntax highlighting
- Code completion
- Load to database
- Header generation
- F3 jump to code