# PL/SQL Developer alternative

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

We have a lot of our business logic in an oracle database. So we use a lot of **PL/SQL** code. We build, test, and debug PL/SQL packages, procedures, triggers, and functions.
Our current tool is the PL/SQL Developer (http://www.allroundautomations.com/).

What are your tools for PL/SQL coding and why do you prefer it to the PL/SQL Developer?
Or would you prefer to work with PL/SQL Developer?

There are some alternatives I know (but have no experience):

- Oracle SQL Developer
- Toad for Oracle
- TOra
- SQuirreL SQL

Comment: Actually, for PL/SQL coding I prefer PL/SQL Developer...

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496680/what-is-the-perfect-toolbox-for-pl-sql-development

Comment: I'll stick to PL SQL developer. There seems to be no real good ide for pl/sql developing... Toad, SQL-Developer and PL/SQL-Developer are the three big ones.

Comment: I tried to move to another tool sometimes but I always get back to PL/SQL Developer. It's by far the best of all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say, keep using the tool you currently feel comfortable with. My primary tool is pl/sql developer, which I started with, and which I've been using for years, but I also tried both TOAD and Oracle SQL developer. They both have some of their unique and very nice features, and both miss some of pl/sql developer features, that are crucial for me. So, as long as none of these IDEs appeared to be ultimate for me, I came to a conclusion that switching to a new IDE while I feel ok with developer is nothing but a whim. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been used Toad for many years and it  my opinion it is the best tool for Oracle, but I use it for many other tasks besides PL\SQL development but the price is rather high.

Although, in my company some developers uses Oracle SQL Developer only for PL/SQL and they are quite happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I use Oracle SQL Developer, and it is decent, but it's free - and you get what you pay for.  There are a few irritating features (such as the ability to create documents of any type but the inability to see them to then open them) and it sometimes seems a bit slow.  It seems to be more designed as a GUI for script writing than a full debugging IDE -  although the features are there they are a little clunky.  On the whole, it meets my needs, though - and the price is right.  And my opinion is that is will keep getting better as it is used by more people.

If free is not a requirement, I have heard great things about both Toad and PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, we use TOAD, but I would say it is inertia as much as anything else (i.e. we've always used it).

Stepping from TOAD to SQL Developer, I prefer TOAD for most things, even though SQL Developer seems less buggy - but that may be familiarity.

I'm not sure whether I would pay the price for TOAD if we did not already have licenses.

However, I will say that I do most of my actual PL/SQL coding (as opposed to testing/debugging) using e-editor (a Windows equivalent to Textmate) because as a code editor I find TOAD (and SQL Developer) to be pretty limited. They feel a decade behind other language IDEs (Eclipse, XCode, etc). Just the ability to have simple auto-complete speeds me up dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Eclipse with the plugin "Toby's PLSQL Editor". Gives you most of the normal functions like syntax highlighting, code completion and F3 to jump to code. It relies upon your source organised into directories that roughly correspond to schemas.

Comment: The code completion and the highlighting is great! But i miss basis features like search the db etc. Just for coding and nothing else it is an option.

Comment: Yeah - it can do compile to DB but won't let you browse the DB ala TOAD/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I use both SQL Developer and SQL Navigator.

SQL Developer is good for a free tool but lacks some of the finesse and "nice to haves" that SQL Navigator has but you have to pay for SQL Navigator.

A lot of IDE choice comes down to personal preference and what you are used to using.

I have used TOAD in the past and was more than happy with it, often I do not have much choice which IDE I use as I work on client sites and have to use whichever IDE is standard for them on their equipment.

For the record, I have found SQL Developer to be a little slow at times when typing queries etc. but that might just be the PC I'm currently using....

Comment: Ouch, downvote but no comment on why? Not really very helpful for those that come along looking for an answer is it...(not to mention it's been four years since I wrote this answer).

Comment: He downvoted everything. We don't know why.

Comment: I upvoted all the answers that look reasonable and that answer the question.  You may want to do the same.

Comment: I'm the mean down-voter.  :)  I down voted everything because these questions and answers don't belong here anymore and are "not useful".  I understand that 4 years ago these questions were tolerated.  But "recommend a tool" questions don't work on this site and should be discouraged or closed if possible.  I understand this is a bit unfair to some users but it's what's best for the site.

Comment: @JonHeller, downvoting without an explanation is counter productive so thanks for the reason, however, by downvoting you do not then get the answers or the question removed. It would be far better (and fairer to those that took the time to offer opinions and answers) to take your issue to a moderator and request them to remove the question. They are, after all, the arbiter for the site.

Answer (score -1):

There is JetBrains 0xDBE, but it is only in beta and may not be very mature yet.